# Usage of "not only--but also" in unbalanced structure

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions

> Parents not only gives us love but also protection against any danger.

Why does the author use **unbalanced structure**
between "not only----but also"? Can I  change this sentence into

> Parents not only give us love but also give us protection against any danger?

Would my sentence have different in meaning with the
given sentence?

Comment: Yes, I also believe the aurhor's sentence isn't a good one since _parallel structures_ were ignored while writing it. He wanted to avoid the repetition of give us but didn't do a good job on that. I think the last two sentences provided by Max are examples of graceful writing. Although nowadays with this creative writing and stuff, things get much more related to _one's style_. ;) maybe the author wanted to put more emphasis on _love_ by avoiding wording around it.

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer ***why*** the author did that; I can't read minds. But I can say that the author's sentence makes sense. So that might be why the faulty usage is made and overlooked.

You are right to be suspicious. Proper usage of the correlative conjunction [*not only... but (also)*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123795/how-to-use-the-not-only-but-also-construction) requires parallelism.

> 1. Parents not only **give** us love but also **give** us protection against any danger. (OP)
> 2. Parents not only **give** us love but also **protect** us against danger.
> 3. Parents give us not only **love** but also **protection**.

Yes, your example is equivalent in meaning to the author's sentence.